# Mirror model to create autoencoder. (Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, convolution, autoencoder

I have a model in keras and I want to use it as a feature extractor in an autoencoder configuration. The first test I want to do is to mirror the model and use the original version as the encoder, and the second one as the decoder.

e.g. if the blocks on the original model goes
`input->A->B->C->output`
I want to get

```
input->A->B->C->(latent space)->C->B->A->reconstructed_input
```

However, the original model is not small and I am quite new to keras. It has a number of blocks defined with which the total model is built. What I am confused about is the order I have to follow when I reverse things. There are several convolutional, reshaping, and dense layers, as well as skip connections, and I am not sure about the strategy I should follow with each individual case. I know for a fact that I should replace `Conv2d` layers with `Conv2DTranspose` to upscale the feature maps back to the original image, but that's about it. I am baffled by the rest.

Does anyone have any recommendations or resources I could follow to make my life easier?

Cheers!